# How I can make a window and an input box in Python?

Tags: python

Make a window 400*400 
And there is an input box there
I can't do anything right now
Can you help me with my programming?

Comment: python has GUI modules to create windows with widgets like input box. You can use (preinstalled) `tkinter` or (external) `PyQt5`, `PySide`, `wxPython`, `PyGtk`, etc.

Comment: Check [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) to make a window.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find below a way to create the GUI using wxPython.
I also recommend the tutorial [here](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/).

```
import wx


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title='My First GUI Project', size=(400, 400))
        ####---- Widgets
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.inputText = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, size=(200, 25), pos=(20, 20))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) strongly recommends only answering well-asked questions